# Spring Boot Multi Module and Fat jar with Shared Features

Tags: spring-boot

Experts,

I need some expert advice on how to approach the below use case in spring boot.

1. I need to have a maven multi-module approach to my project.
2. I need to have a single jar as output of the final build process.
3. There are to be common modules for controllers, data access and other functionality
4. Other modules are to be created based on functionality domain for eg a module for Payroll, a module for Admin etc etc.
5. Each domain functional module will then have their own controllers extending the common controller, exception handler and so on.
6. Each module will also have its own set of thyme leaf pages.

The reason for following such an approach is we have development in phases and we will be rolling out based on functional modules.

Here are the issues that I can sense using this approach.

1. Where do I add the spring web dependency? If I add to the parent pom - it gets replicated across the children and there will be port conflict issues as each module loads. the same issue will also be there the moment I add it to two child modules.
2. How do I build the fat jar which has all the jars from all modules and works as the final deployment?

All the text that I read i can't see anything even close to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I suggest you look into and watch some presentations on custom autoconfigurations. There is too much here to unpack into a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

AD1. They will not unless you are trying to setup independent application context in each module. Of course you can do that(it might be complicated but I believe it's achievable), but for me it's an overkill. Personally I think it's better to have one application context and rely on scanning components that are present in classpath.

AD2. The structure in maven might be a little bit complicated and overwhelming at first glance but it makes sense. Here's how I see it:

1. Create a parent module that will aggregate each module in project and will declare library/plugin dependencies for submodules.
2. Create 1-N shared submodules that will be used in other modules. With come common logic, utils, etc.
3. Create 1-N submodules that will be handling your business logic
4. Create an application submodule that creates application context and loads configuration and components from classpath
5. Create a submodule that will be responsible for packaging process, either to war, jar, uber-jar or whatever else you desire. Maven jar plugin should do that for you. For executable uber-jar, you have dedicated tool from spring.

Now you can choose three ways(these ways I know) of loading your modules.
 1. Include some modules in maven build based on the build configuration via maven profiles and let spring IoC container load all the components he finds in the classpath
 2. Include all of the modules in maven build and load them depending on spring active profiles - you can think about it as of feature flag. You annotate your components or configuration class with @Profile("XYZ") telling spring IoC container whether to instantiate component or not. You will need (most flexible solution) to provide a property file which tells spring which profiles are active and thus which modules should be loaded
 3. Mix of these two above.

Solution 1 pros:

- build is faster (modules that are not included will be skipped during build)
- final build file is light (modules that are not included are... not included ;))
- nobody can run module that is not present

Solution 1 contras:

- project descriptor in maven may explode as you might have many different profiles

Solution 2 pros:

- it's fairly easy and fun to maintain modules from code
- less mess in project descriptor

Solution 2 contras:

- somebody can run module that is not intended to be run as it's present in classpath, but just excluded during runtime via spring active profiles
- final build file might be overweight - unused code is still present in code
- build might take longer - unused code will be compiled

### Summary:

It's not easy to build well structured project from scratch. It's much more easier to create a monolith and then split it into modules. It's because if you already created a project, you've probably already identified all the domains and relations between them.

Over past 8 years of using `maven`, I honestly and strongly recommend using `gradle` as it's far more flexible than `maven`. Maven is really great tool, but when it comes to weird customization it often fails as it's build capabilities rely on plugins. You can't write a piece of code on the fly to perform some custom build behaviour while buidling your project, you must have a dedicated plugin for doing that. If such plugin exists it's fine, if it's not you will probably end up writing your own and handling its shipment, so anyone in your company can easily perform project build.

I hope it helps. Have fun ;)

Comment: why is build tools even coming into this? Spring boot autoconfigurations, are the way this should be implemented and OP should research and try something before asking for solutions to his problem.

Comment: well, probably because one of OP's requirement was to have multi module maven project.